# Search using 2 fields concatenated in one ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, textfield

I'm wandering if you can help me with this. I need to search using 2 fields of my DB, Cod + number. I show this in one column, for ex. cod ACE + number 003, it shows ACE003, so how can I search in one textfield for the two option. Now if you enter ACE003 in the field, nothing return, but if you type ACE, of course it works. This is my code..

index.html

```
<%= text_field_tag :s_cod, params[:s_cod] %>  

<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.cod + '%03d' % item.num.to_s %></td>
    ...
```

Controller

```
if (params[:s_cod] != nil) or (params[:s_rotulo] != nil) or (params[:s_den_cont] != nil) or (params[:s_marca] != nil)
  @items = View_item.all.order("date_expired ASC").page(params[:page]).per(15).search(params[:s_cod], params[:s_rotulo], params[:s_den_cont], params[:s_marca])
```

You can see many field that I use to search. I have to use one field to search for cod + number.

Model

## Search section

```
def self.search(s_codigo, s_rotulo, s_den_cont, s_marca)
where("cod ilike :s_c and rotulo ilike :s_r and den_cont ilike :s_d and marca ilike :s_m", s_c: "%#{s_cod}%", s_r: "%#{s_rotulo}%", s_d: "%#{s_den_cont}%", s_m: "%#{s_marca}%")
end
```

How can I search by cod + number using one textfield?. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE (SOLVED)
In my view in the postgress DB I use

```
.concat(items.cod, to_char(items.num, 'fm000'::text)) AS codigo
```

Comment: What database do you use? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Something else?

Comment: Postgress, tks Mr... see the UPDATE

Comment: Please don't answer your question in the question. You are allowed to add an answer to your own question that you can then select as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to query for the concatenated value of the two columns.

In MySQL, use the CONCAT() function like

```
where("concat(code,number) LIKE :s_c",s_c: "%#{s_cod}%")
```

I believe the PostgreSQL should be similar, but I'm not 100% familiar with the syntax

Comment: Tks Brian, i'm using postgress, see the UPDATE with the solution.